# Where is the option in Eclipse IDE to remove long identifier strings that precede the actual variable?

Tags: eclipse, variables

I am using Eclipse to debug a C++ application.
Can anyone please tell me how to hide these strings in the variable listing window? (highlighted in yellow box)
It is not useful information right now, and it is so wide that it pushes the actual string (which is what I am trying to see) out of view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73aC.png

I have tried looking through the options dialog in Window -> Preferences, but can't find anything to remove it.